# Slide DIV Right to Left with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I'm using jQuery code to animate a div from left to right on load, and then by clicking the close button the div hides from right to left. It's working fine, it's just not going left to right horizontally but diagonally. What am I doing wrong? Here's an example of the code I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/N8NpE/2/

```
$(function(){
    $("#content-box").hide(0).delay(0).show(500);
});

$(function(){
    $("#ClosePanel").click(function () {
        $("#content-box").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `.animate()` instead of `.hide()` and `.show()`. This will give you a little more control over everything.

```
$("#content-box").animate({'width': 240},500);
```

And to close, include a callback function to set display to none after the animation:

```
$("#content-box").animate({'width': 0},500,function(){
       $("#content-box").css('display','none');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N8NpE/6/

Comment: All posted techniques worked, but I liked this one better because it gives more control as you said. The only thing is that it is not sliding in, it just show up and when closing it do slide to the right but it's squeezing the text instead of actually sliding it. Here's the [link](http://www.azurpanama.com/index.php?page=fullbg-test) where I used the script.

Comment: You must initially specify a width of 0 on that element in your css, as a starting point for your animation. As for the text 'squeezing', to avoid that you would have to have a wrapper around the text with a fixed width, and then set `overflow: hidden;` on the content-box (the element that is animating, not it's child with the fixed width). That way, the content box will shrink in width, but it's contents will remain a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks so much Blake, it worked great. There's a small issue though. I need to add a 5s delay before the box slides to the right, so I added a .delay(5000) to the code '$("#content-box").delay(5000).animate({'width': 300},1000);' and now it first show the text and after 5s it disappear and start the animation as it should. [Here's the example ](http://azurpanama.com/index.php?page=fullbg-test)

Comment: The `overflow: hidden;` css needs to be on the div with the id of content box (#content-box). This is what keeps the text out of sight until the width of the box becomes great enough for the text to be visible.

Answer (score 3):

You should include jQuery UI in your script and change your function a little bit:

```
$(function(){
$("#content-box").hide(0).delay(0).toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N8NpE/4/

Comment: Thanks Maxim, this code worked and is very helpful but I'm trying to load less scripts into the page. But I'll sure use it in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#content-box').animate({width: 'toggle'});`

http://jsfiddle.net/U7wGt/

Comment: As all the others, this one also worked, but I'm trying to diminish the use of loading codes. Thanks for your help Joseph.